# Well ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ using inductive sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

In this book (Elementary Real Analysis by Thomson-Bruckner p.22), $\mathbb{N}=\left\{ 1,2,...\right\}$ (In some, $0\in\mathbb{N}$).

In an exercise, a set $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ is inductive if $1\in S$ and $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\,\,x\in S\Rightarrow (x+1)\in S$

I show then that the intersection of the family of all inductive sets is itself inductive.

They define then $\mathbb{N}$ to be that smallest inductive set and I prove then the Principle of Induction using it.

Now I have to prove the Well Ordering of $\mathbb{N}$.

I know that, since Principle of Induction is correct, Well Ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ is also correct. But I wanted to challenge myself and prove Well Ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ using "$\mathbb{N}$ to be that smallest inductive set" as I did for Principle of Induction, without using any other proposition like Archimede Property or the Principle of Induction itself:

> Let $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ such as $S$ is inductive (i.e., property stated in the Principle of Induction).
>
> "$\mathbb{N}$ to be that smallest inductive set" so $\mathbb{N}\subset S$ thus $\mathbb{N}=S$ which proves the Principle of Induction.

I wrote a prove for the Well Ordering but I'm not sure if it's correct.

It's a bit long so could you please tell me if you have an easier?

My attempt:

Let $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ such as $S\neq\emptyset$.

If $S=\mathbb{N}$ then $\min S=1$. We're done.

If $S\neq\mathbb{N}$ then $S$ isn't inductive and so $1\notin S$ or $\exists n_0\in S,\,(n_0+1)\notin S$.

If $1\in S$ then $\min S=1$. We're done.

If $1\notin S$.

**Suppose $\forall n\in S,\,(n+1)\in S$**

Suppose $S$ has no minimum,i.e., $\forall n\in S,\,\exists n_0\in S,\,n_0\le n-1$

Let $n_0\in S$. Thus $\exists n_1\in S,\, n_1\le n_0-1$

$n_1\in S$. Thus $\exists n_2\in S,\, n_2\le n_1-1$

We can repeat the same prossess until we reach:

$n_{n_0-1}\in S$. Thus $\exists n_{n_0}\in S,\, n_{n_0}\le n_{n_0-1}-1$

By sommation: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n_0-1}n_{k+1}\le\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n_0-1}n_k-1$

Thus $n_{n_0}\le 0$ and $n_{n_0}\in S$, contradiction.

**Suppose $\exists n_0\in S,\,(n_0+1)\notin S$**

If $n_0=\min S$ we're done if not $\exists n_1\in S,\,n_1\le n_0-1$

If $n_1=\min S$ we're done if not $\exists n_2\in S,\,n_2\le n_1-1$

We can repeat the same prossess until we reach:

If $n_{n_0}=\min S$ we're done if not $\exists n_{n_0+1}\in S,\,n_{n_0+1}\le n_{n_0}-1$

We do the same as above and find a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $S$ has no minimum element. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $\varphi(n)$ be the statement $$\forall k\in\Bbb N(k\le n\to k\notin S)\;,$$ and let $A=\{n\in\Bbb N:\varphi(n)\}$. Clearly $1\in A$. Suppose that $A$ is not inductive; then there is an $n_0\in A$ such that $n_0+1\notin A$. Then $\varphi(n_0)$, so $k\notin S$ for each $k\le n_0$, but $\neg\varphi(n_0+1)$, so there is a $k\le n_0+1$ such that $k\in S$. Thus, $n_0+1\in S$, but $k\notin S$ for $k\le n_0$, so $n_0+1=\min S$. This contradiction shows that $A$ is inductive, so $A=\Bbb N$, and $S=\varnothing$.

Comment: That was pretty much my suggestion, but see the comments under my now-deleted answer.

Comment: Isn't it $\phi (n_0)$ so $k\notin S$ for each $k\le n_O$? And $\neg\phi (n_0+1)$ so there is $k\le n_0+1$ such as $k\in S$? Because $\phi (n)$ is $k\le n\Rightarrow k\notin S$

Comment: @Scientifica: Yes, somehow I got those backwards. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks.
@Asaf Karagila, well you said Property of induction to use recursive proof. But still thanks for answer

Comment: @Scientifica: I’m not actually using the property of induction; I’m using only the fact that $\Bbb N$ is the smallest inductive set. The argument is very much like the one used to *prove* the induction property, but I’m not actually *using* that property.

Comment: @Scientifica: "you said Property of induction to use recursive proof", say what?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila You're idea was the same but you said as Hint use property of induction. But still I thank you for your participation.

Comment: @Brian M.Scott Yes you didn't mentionned it but I understood that you used the "smallest inductive set" since $A\subset\mathbb{N}$. I'm just now trying to understand why $S=\emptyset$ (I can hear television near me so I can't concentrate well ^^)

Comment: @Scientifica: If $S\ne\varnothing$, pick $n\in S$; then $n\notin A$, so $A\ne\Bbb N$. (I solved the television problem years ago: I don’t have one!)

Comment: @Scientifica 4 seconds before you sent that comment I got it! Thank you

Comment: @Scientifica: Great!